# How to delete some of those enormous files in System Volume Information\ in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

I've installed that script that enables me to take ownership of that folder, but I still can't delete any of the files (I assume the older ones would be OK to delete). What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

That folder contains system restore points which can be quite large. Change your System Restore settings if it is taking too much space. You shouldn't try to delete these files manually, because the system expects them to be there.

Comment: Wow! That was a quick reply. Thanks! 

Ok, I'll take your advice.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Limits

#### 1. Description

**If** you use method from item 2 of this answer:

1. You save last restore point file,
2. Another restore points was deleted.

It's preferred for me.

#### 2. Environment

It works for my Windows 10. I don't test in Windows Vista.

---

### 2. Method

<kbd>Win+R</kbd> → print `cleanmgr` → <kbd>Enter</kbd> → `OK` → `More Options` → `Clean up…`

[image: Cleanup]

All system restore points

**except** the last restore point

must be deleted.

[image: System Restore Folder]

---

### 3. Alternative method

**If** you want to delete custom file from `System Volume Infomation` folder,

use [**Hossein Fakouri method**](https://superuser.com/a/961246/572069).

Make sure that you know what you are removing.

---

### 4. Extra links

- [**System restore points in Windows 10**](http://remontka.pro/system-restore-points-windows-10/#delete_restore_point) (in Russian).

Answer (score 0):

**On XP**, you can delete old System Restore points via the Disk Cleanup wizard (`Start Menu > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Disk Cleanup`).  On the `More Options` tab, clicking the `Clean up...` button deletes **all but the most recent** System Restore point.

I hope Vista provides a more granular control over deleting old points.

Comment: There are clear instructions in the Vista Help about how to do the same thing with Disk Cleanup in Vista. To get to the instructions, just search the Help on "Delete a restore point"