# How to delete a file inside system volume information folder in windows server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I checked lots of ways to delete a file inside the System Volume Information folder (not a system file, a file I've copied there accidentally) but none of them worked for me.

First I changed security and ownership of the file and get full control to administrator. then tried to disable System File Protection (which I couldn't find in Windows Server 2008).

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! just use command prompt with administrator account:

```
takeown /f "C:\System Volume Information" /R /A
```

then

```
cacls "C:\System Volume Information" /T /C /E /P Administrators:F
```

and now just delete it by a simple command

```
del "C:\System Volume Information\Sample File.txt"
```

that's it!

Comment: How do I restore full admin rights, to reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply right click the remove able disk.Select the option **Open as Portable Device**. Now delete the file from **System Volume Information folder** you want to remove.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. It does not mention removable disks.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have Cygwin installed, the following commands worked for me and I didn't need to modify all of the permissions/ACLs of specified files in the current directory (i.e., 'C:\System Volume Information') and all subdirectories as the previously mentioned 'takeown' and 'cacls' commands do.

CAUTION: the 'C:\System Volume Information' folder contains important system files and folders such as system Restore Points, Windows backups, chkdsk logs, etc. so use caution when manipulating any files and folders in this folder.

To delete a file or folder:

$ cd "/cygdrive/c/System Volume Information"

$ rm test_file.txt

$ rmdir test_folder

You can also move a file or folder with the following commands:

$ cd "/cygdrive/c/System Volume Information"

$ mv test_file.txt /cygdrive/c/temp

$ mv test_folder /cygdrive/c/temp

Not sure why you can move files into the "C:\System Volume Information" folder using Windows explorer or cmd.exe, but not delete or move files out of the "C:\System Volume Information" folder using Windows explorer or cmd.exe even when logged in as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the "System Volume Information" folder in a removable drive with FAT32 format: 
`attrib -s -h -r "T:\System Volume Information"`